# how to render components reading it from json

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Example I have some json data and I want to render components as described in json

```
const myJson = {
    hbox : {icon1 : "image",file_name : "text", icon2 : "image" }
}
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native'; 

const components = {
    icon: Image,
    text: Text
};

function SimpleComponent(componentType) {
      const SpecificStory = components[componentType];
      return <SpecificStory />;
}
```

how to render this components inside View component recursively

```
function readJson (json) {
    let arr = Object.keys(json);
    for (let i in arr){
        if(typeof json[arr[i]] == 'string'){
            SimpleComponent(json[arr[i]]);
        } else { readJson(json[arr[i]])}
    }

}

render () {
    return ( <View>{readJson(myJson)}</View>) 
}
```

is it possible like I wrote above

Comment: what do you mean by render components, do you want to poll data after some seconds?

Comment: I want to render some components when I get json data from server

Answer (score 0):

You could make a landing component, suppose `GeneralComponent`.

Use something like this: `<GeneralComponent type="ComponentType" data={allDataYouNeedInCop}/>`

In `onCreate` of the `GeneralComponent`, check what is written in `props.type`, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you will have a lot of cases.

**1- Recursive function**

So about recursive function (readJson) you can use map function instead.
for exemple :

```
let result =  myJson.map( (elem) => {
   return SimpleComponent(elem);
});
render () {
   return ( <View>{result}</View>) 
}
```

Comment: In my case expected that json elements also can be json type, how in that case

Comment: So in this way, you should use your recursive function.